# Manage clipboard Tcl/Tk

Tags: tcl, clipboard, tk-toolkit

I'm having troubles managing the Windows clipboard in Tcl/Tk. It seems to act pretty randomly : sometimes, when I use the following

```
clipboard clear
clipboard append $myVar
```

It entirely works, and puts the wanted value in my clipboard. Sometimes it doesn't, without me being able to identify in which different circumstances the copying worked. Is there something I should know about ?

Comment: It probably depends on what other applications are doing, as the clipboard is a per-user entity (and has to be; otherwise you couldn't cut-n-paste between applications).

Comment: I've never used the Tk `clipboard` command before, I can only confirm that what I have tested so far _"works"._
As an alternative on Windows platform you may also try with TWAPI extension, maybe the clipboard management it's more system-wide than Tk itself. Worth a try: [TWAPI clipboard API link](https://twapi.magicsplat.com/v4.5/clipboard.html)